# Excel Userform animated dots on loading

Tags: excel, vba

There are a lot of tutorials in the Internet. However I was not able to find anything suitable. Is there any way to make animated dots on loading?

The idea is to make a loop of animated dots `.....` on userform so they would appear one after another and then would start over after some amount of dots.

So I input a dot to Label1 and move it to left after certain time criteria?

My current code for UserForm:

```
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
HideTitleBar.HideTitleBar Me
    Call loadingdots
End Sub
```

Code for `Private Sub Workbook_Open()`:

```
Loading.Show (vbModeless)

Dim RngCom As Range
Dim RngTurb As Range
Dim RngGen As Range

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:06"))

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MAIN").ScrollArea = "$A$1:$BL$45"
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
  etc...
  Unload Loading
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  End Sub
```

Comment: You have to take label control and type dot as text on label. Then use `label1.left` (left, right, top property) to move them. You have to use timer control procedures to move them automatically after a certain time like 100 milliseconds, 200 milliseconds or 500 milliseconds.

Comment: To add to what Harun said, you can also use the font property to increase/decrease the size of the dot (font size), in order to simulate "animation".

Comment: Can you please add some example? I can't get it to work see my edited question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most elegant solution would likely to be the [OnTime method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.ontime).

Place a label inside your UF and remove the caption. Next, in a regular module (so not that of the UF), place this subroutine:

```
'this function ensures the self-activating sub will stop if the UF has been closed
Public Function IsLoaded(form As String) As Boolean
Dim frm As Object
For Each frm In VBA.UserForms
    If frm.Name = form Then
        IsLoaded = True
        Exit Function
    End If
Next frm
IsLoaded = False
End Function


Public Sub loadingdots()

If IsLoaded("UserForm1") = True Then
    If Len(UserForm1.Label1.Caption = 4) Then
        UserForm1.Label1.Caption = "."
    Else
        UserForm1.Label1.Caption = UserForm1.Label1.Caption & "."
    End If
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "loadingdots"
End If

End Sub
```

Next, call the self-activating sub when the UF gets initialised

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Call loadingdots
End Sub
```

Do not forget to change the references to the UF to the right name.

Comment: This work in other userforms, I have tested it. However there is a problem with splash screen userform. For some reason there is no animation and I see only first dot and it is not proceeding forward. What may be the problem?

Comment: I don't know what that UF looks like and what code is inside it. I know RefEdits can mess up greatly.