# Loading dots splash screen on Workbook_Open

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code for "Bubbles" imitation while loading a workbook. I was trying to make them appear on Workbook_open but something is wrong and my code does not work correct. Dots are not running. I think the problem in current code is with `Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")`

Code utilized from: [Excel Userform animated dots on loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56321140/excel-userform-animated-dots-on-loading)

If I run UserForm separately just by `.Show` command, everything works.

Here is my code for UserForm:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim AppXCenter, AppYCenter As Long
    Dim bytOpacity As Byte
    bytOpacity = 192 ' variable keeping opacity setting
    hWnd = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", Me.Caption)
    Call SetWindowLong(Me.hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(Me.hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) Or WS_EX_LAYERED)
    Call SetLayeredWindowAttributes(Me.hWnd, 0, bytOpacity, LWA_ALPHA)


    AppXCenter = Application.Left + (Application.Width / 2)
    AppYCenter = Application.Top + (Application.Height / 2)
    With Me
    .StartUpPosition = 0
    .Top = AppYCenter - (Me.Height / 2)
    .Left = AppXCenter - (Me.Width / 2)
    End With

HideTitleBar.HideTitleBar Me

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "loadingdots"

End Sub
```

Loadingdots:

```
Public Sub loadingdots()

If IsLoaded("Loading") = True Then
    If Len(Loading.Label2.Caption) = 10 Then
        Loading.Label2.Caption = "."
    Else
        Loading.Label2.Caption = Loading.Label2.Caption & "."
    End If
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "loadingdots"
End If

End Sub
```

Check if is loaded:

```
Public Function IsLoaded(form As String) As Boolean
Dim frm As Object
For Each frm In VBA.UserForms
    If frm.Name = form Then
        IsLoaded = True
        Exit Function
    End If
Next frm
IsLoaded = False
End Function
```

Comment: So where is the sub called "loadingdots"?

Comment: Note that `Dim AppXCenter, AppYCenter As Long` only declares the last variable as `Long` but the first as `Variant` you need to specify a type for **every** variable in VBA: `Dim AppXCenter As Long, AppYCenter As Long` otherwise VBA assumes `Variant`.

Comment: `If IsLoaded("Loading") = True Then` relies on a populated variable. Try setting `IsLoaded` as a Public variable so it retains its value